# ImageView with adjustViewBounds inconsistently being shown inside ConstraintLayout on inflation

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I'm using a RecyclerView to display a grid of images. When an image is tapped a Dialog Fragment inflates a larger version of that image varying in aspect ratio which is why I'm using adjustViewBounds. The images are coming in from URLs from the Instagram API. Image processing is being done using Glide.

When I use a different layout or no layout I don't encounter this issue. If I use Glide to resize all the images that are displayed to be the same aspect ratio I don't encounter this issue as well.

Visual [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEBHY.jpg) of the issue

Dialog Fragment inflated view.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
                name="url"
                type="String" />

        <variable
                name="hashTag"
                type="String" />
    </data>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/EERIE_BLACK"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_image_constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:imageUrl="@{url}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:src="@drawable/image_2" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="#PlaceHolderTag"
                    android:textColor="@color/BABY_POWDER"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="#Hashtag" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Set the ratio for image view

Comment: @Jaymin The images don't all have the same ratio. I want the ImageView to match what ever the image is.

Answer (score 0):

if you want ImageView match_parent or full,
you can add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```